# How do I specify context (platform/device information) when using OpenCL?

Tags: c++, opencv, opencl

How do I specify context (platform/device information) when using OpenCL calls in place of OpenCV calls when using OpenCL library for OpenCV 2.4.8 in C++?

I could do it for OpenCV version 2.4.6 but I could not work it out for OpenCV version 2.4.8

Here's what I did for ver. 2.4.6:

`std::vector<ocl::Info> oclinfo;
    int ocld = ocl::getDevice(oclinfo);
    cout<< ocld;
    for ( int i=0; i< oclinfo.size(); i++ )
    {
    cout << "OpenCL Device" << i << ":" << oclinfo[i].DeviceName[0] << endl;
    }
    ocl::setDevice(oclinfo[0], 0);`

Answer (score 0):

I've not used version 2.4.8, but for version 2.4.9 you can use this [link](http://ehc.ac/p/emgucv/opencv/ci/e8d9ed89559ad33167d23e562b52d18bb0c9f817/tree/modules/ocl/perf/main.cpp?diff=8e75947a7d897703ec7b1b051b65d5812fac362a)
also you can set environment variable OPENCV_OPENCL_DEVICE for default config.